# Network socket use not reflected in netstat

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, netstat

The total number of sockets reported in use is not reflected in netstat or ss commands.  Co-relating will help me resolve a socket leak issue.

Here is what I have:

> ss -s

Produces

```
Total: 4676 (kernel 12714)
TCP:   6298 (estab 323, closed 5201, orphaned 1, synrecv 0, timewait 1996/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*     12714     -         -
RAW   0         0         0
UDP   25        14        11
TCP   1097      15        1082
INET          1122      29        1093
FRAG          0         0         0
```

> netstat -an|wc -l

Produces

```
3319
```

> cat /proc/net/sockstat

Produces

```
sockets: used 4677
TCP: inuse 15 orphan 1 tw 1997 alloc 4303 mem 3899
UDP: inuse 14 mem 8
UDPLITE: inuse 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

All were run at the same time.

I am unable to find out what those extra sockets as reported by **cat /proc/net/sockstat** & **ss -s** (Total: 4676 or 4677) which is not reflected by **netstat -an** or **ss -a** (Total: 3319).  There is a socket leak that I am trying to identify which is the difference between the two, and that difference is growing every day.  I know the process causing the leak and of course the workaround is to simply restart the process (which I am doing for now). How do I identify the actual IP/Connection/Socket information of the leaking sockets so I can tell the development exactly which IP call in their program is likely leaking socket connections?  The netstat -an command seems to ignore those "extra" connections that are there in the output.  Or perhaps I am missing something else obvious.  Once I restart the process I can see a huge recovery in the socket usage and then the steady growth begins again as the system is put to use.  Please help specifically or if there is another way to identify leaking sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found when you run `ss -an` and `netstat -an` and compare the result. All ordinary (tcp, udp, unix) sockets are present in both outputs but the `ss` output contains extra lines with netlink sockets and packet sockets. They are the lines with `nl`, `p_raw` and `p_dgr`.

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering.  However I ran:


   ` ss -an|awk '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c`

and

   ` ss -an|awk '{print $1}'|sort|uniq -c`

and

    `ss -s`


The total that comes in ss -s does not co-relate to any combination of numbers in the two commands above it.  Still have no idea what the total count means in ss -s